# How do I spawn a new process while another process is running?

Tags: linux, shell, spawning

I am writing a shell script that will perform 2 tasks. One task will start up a program that must keep running continuously. Within the same script, the 2nd task is to be initiated that will start up another program. But when the first is running continuously, how can i start another within the same script ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ill be starting a MongoDB server. In the first task that is.

Comment: Check e.g. the [Bash manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), especially the sections about "Coprocesses" and "Job control"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably looking to *background* a task. Generally, you do this like so:

```
sleep 30 &
sleep 30 &
jobs
echo 'Waiting for all jobs to complete.'
wait
```

The backgrounding is handled by the **&** symbol at the end of the line.

#### See Also

- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html#Lists
- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html

Comment: But will this work if the script is being executed remotely via Putty ?

Comment: As long as you're connected. See [nohup](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/nohup-invocation.html) if you want it to remain running after you log out.

Comment: @Cygnus: Note: nohup is not enough. You must make sure all input/output from the script (and any commands) is untied from the shell (so you need to redirect output/error/input to files (/dev/null is usefull for this)).

Answer (score 2):

Add an ampersand after the command:

~$ myprogram&

It will place the program running in the background.

Comment: That was my initial thought. But the script may be executed remotely (via Putty). Would it work in that case ?

Comment: Yes, no problem. If you are logged in via putty (or any other SSH client), the OS will run any command (including scripts and what they spawn) on that (virtual) terminal.

Comment: Thanks !! Will be trying it now !!